# Is there any way to make the Scrollview scroll up an extra 100px React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I have a component that contains a scrollview. It also have a bottom sheet component. Is there a way to increase the distance of the scrollview when my bottom sheet is active. When my bottom sheet is active I need my scrollview to scroll 100 extra px when my bottom sheet is active because the bottom sheet covers some of the content

```
<View>
  <Scrollview>
    ...items to scroll
  </Scrollview>
  <ButtomSheet />
</View>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some state that manages if/when `BottomSheet` is active, you can add a style to scroll view conditionally. Like:

```
<View>
  <Scrollview style={bottomSheetActive ? {height: 200px} : {height: 100px}>
    {children}
  </ScrollView>
  {bottomSheetActive && (<BottomSheet />)}
</View>
```

Comment: Yes but how do we get the current height. need to be able to add addition 100px to the existing height when bottonSheetActive

Comment: You could either use [`onContentSizeChange`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#oncontentsizechange) to get the value, or you could use like, additional padding in the case that bottomSheetActive evaluates true.

Comment: can you please provide an example using onContentSizeChange